# How to scrape the website table without rounding integer values?

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup, rounding

I am scraping the tables from a German website. Germans use comma(,) for decimal(.) and decimal for comma. When I scrape the table then it automatically round or convert the data. For example if the value is "two thousand" which is in German written as 2.000. BS4 convert it into two (2)

Is there any solution by which I can scrape without changing the values?

This is my code.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://buchholz-stadtwerke.de/wasseranalyse.html"

df = pd.read_html(requests.get(url).text, flavor="bs4")
df = pd.concat(df)
```

Comment: I try `df = pd.read_html(url, flavor="bs4")` and working well, what is your pandas version?

Comment: oh ok... '1.0.3'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this example, you might want to replace `,` with `.` to get proper decimal number representation:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://buchholz-stadtwerke.de/wasseranalyse.html"

df = pd.read_html(requests.get(url).text.replace(",", "."), flavor="bs4")
df = pd.concat(df)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
1         Leitfähigkeit (25°)    µS/cm         2790                    302
2   Sauerstoff (elektrochem.)     mg/l          NaN                   10.9
3                     pH-Wert      NaN  6.5 bis 9.5                   8.06
...
```

EDIT:

As this might work only for this example alone, a better approach is to use `thousands=` and `decimal=` arguments passed in to `pd.read_html()`

Comment: Thanks... I thought we can't use replace directly here. It worked :)

Comment: Sure you can, it's just so-called pain text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `thousands='.'` and  `decimal=','` parameters:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = "https://buchholz-stadtwerke.de/wasseranalyse.html"

df = pd.read_html(requests.get(url).text, flavor="bs4", thousands='.', decimal=',')
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
[                    Parameter  Einheit    Grenzwert Messwert, Februar 2020
0            Wassertemperatur       °C          NaN                    9.8
1         Leitfähigkeit (25°)    µS/cm         2790                    302
2   Sauerstoff (elektrochem.)     mg/l          NaN                   10.9
3                     pH-Wert      NaN  6,5 bis 9,5                   8.06
4             Sättigungsindex      NaN          NaN                   0.01
5         Karbonathärte (dH°)      °dH          NaN                   4.54
6           Gesamthärte (dH°)      °dH          NaN                   6.45
7                Härtebereich      NaN          NaN                  weich
8         Calcitlösekapazität     mg/l            5                   -0.1
9                     Fluorid     mg/l          1.5                   <0,1
10                    Chlorid     mg/l          250                   22.8
11               Nitrit (NO2)     mg/l          0.1                  <0,01
12               Nitrat (NO3)     mg/l           50                   6.29
13                 o-Phosphat     mg/l          NaN                   <0,1
14                     Sulfat     mg/l          250                   28.5
15                     Cyanid     mg/l         0.05                 <0,005
16                    Natrium     mg/l          200                   13.3
17                   Ammonium     mg/l          0.5                   <0,1
18                     Kalium     mg/l          NaN                   1.09
19                  Magnesium     mg/l          NaN                   2.58
20           Ionenbilanz in %        %   -4 bis 4,0                   1.82
21                    Trübung      NTU            1                    0.5
22     Färbung (SAK Hg 436nm)      m-1          0.5                   <0,2
23                  Geschmack      NaN          NaN                   ohne
24                      Arsen     mg/l         0.01                 <0,002
25                Quecksilber     mg/l        0.001                <0,0002
26                       Blei     mg/l         0.01                 <0,003
27                    Cadmium     mg/l        0.003                <0,0005
28                     Kupfer     mg/l            2                  <0,01
29                        Bor     mg/l            1                   0.03
30                  Aluminium     mg/l          0.2                  <0,02
31                    Antimon     mg/l        0.005                 <0,001
32                      Selen     mg/l         0.01                 <0,003
33                      Eisen     mg/l          0.2                  <0,02
34                     Mangan     mg/l         0.05                 <0,005
35       Kolonienzahl bei 22°      /ml          100                      0
36       Kolonienzahl bei 36°      /ml          100                      0
37        Coliforme Bakterien  /100 ml            0                      0]
```